# People don't read. Is dropdown/hover better for this design?

Tags: about

Our website has a home page that has a "about us" section. This section has around 20 staffs (client insist on having this)
[image]

Can't find the best example, but this section would look something like this but with 20 more staffs. We have the image, name, title, description and social media anchors.

Problem: Since its a home page, this is only 1 section out of 4. We don't want this section to be too long. So we can either:

1. Make them just images. Hover over to see text. But the concern is will ppl actually hover over these images? Since people don't read, will people actually hover over just to read?
2. Just have a long page. Nothing wrong with it.
3. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Your reluctance to even include this page in the first place is quite clear. The motivation behind that reluctance is somewhat less so.

"About Us" pages, specifically the photos + brief bios of the key staff, are common, for good reason; they serve several different, valid purposes:

1. They can reassure the user that the company is a real one, staffed by real people, not a faceless corporation or fly-by-night one-man operation.
2. If the company has key staff who are well-known, or known within their niche, this is a fine and unobtrusive opportunity to showcase this fact.
3. It can serve as an ego boost and mild perquisite for the staff involved. Which is fine. There's nothing wrong with this.   Everybody deserves a little ego boost now and again, and the humanizing effect of giving staff members their little slice of the spotlight can be a valuable one.
4. It's an opportunity to do some image management for the company: carefully crafted text (and photography) here can give a picture of the company as a whole -- or the image of that company you wish to present -- as well as the specific individuals being described.
5. A subset of users are absolutely going to read every single word of this page: potential investors, potential acquirers, potential business partners, and potential employees. These are, it hardly needs saying, a very important subset of users, worth catering to.

Are the majority of users likely to read through every bit of text on this page carefully and in detail? No, of course not.  Does that mean you should hide that text or abbreviate it in the interest of not 'wasting space'? Nope.  There's infinite space available. If some of your content is getting in the way of other content, that's a design or layout problem, not a content problem.

There's a certain amount of implied contempt for your audience in your statement that "people don't read". People do read, clearly. They read *differently* online than they do textbooks, or newspapers, or any other text medium; that just means you have to write text that suits how people *do* read in each context.  Short blurbs, such as, say, staff bios, are a great one for online.

Remember one of the reasons why you have a website in the first place: it's to market the company.  This page is an opportunity to do exactly that. Don't hide it, make use of it!

...

Or if none of that grabs you, remember that revealing text only on hover writes off anyone on a mobile, assistive, or touchscreen device. That alone should be reason enough to not do that.

Comment: great answer :) I'd still give some consideration to bphilipnyc's answer since the section doesn't necessarily belong to home page, but I have to agree 100% with your points, nothing to add

Answer (score 2):

Separate this content into a different About Us page that's linked through the home page.  Putting all these images on your home page will cause the page to load slower, even if you use a CDN.  Your mobile users will appreciate it.

Comment: What is CDN? [Ignore this, which gets me past the minimum-character limit.]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting exactly what your problem is. Is it that people don't read the info about the staff or that you don't want to take too much space on the page?

If your problem is the visibility, I would recommend to have the 20 staff members visible with their info and having a hover effect (like coloring the background or making the element bigger, you know what I mean) so it kinda gets the users eye and maybe you can make them read a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

People definitely will not hover, it requires an additional effort no one is willing to invest into a non-crucial content. Plus, some big percentage of audience will view on mobile. Plus, there will be cases when people will land from the google name search and then all they will see would be a number of photos.

So yes, roles and names and a long page. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a design a few months ago (can't remember where) which used a tiled layout and filled the entire page with photos so hovering was inescapable. On hover it had more information (name and a sentence or two) and click would go to a much more informational page about the person. Just another possibility to think about.